# how to insert data into SAP via SAP .NET Connector

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

How to insert data into **SAP** using ***SAPConnector RFC***.

I got this Metadata structure from *QuickWatch*.

```
{IMPORT PARAMETER GT_CPP=null}  SAP.Middleware.Connector.IRfcParameter {SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcParameter}
Metadata    {IMPORT GT_CPP:TABLE ZESMS_CPP_TAB_TT [STRUCTURE ZESMS_CPP_TAB] [optional:null]} SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcParameterMetadata
```

Comment: You'll need to ask a specific question relating to a specific problem, not ask how to approach something.  StackOverflow doesn't do you work for you, it helps you solve problems when you've tried everything you can already.

Comment: If you try to add rows to a SAP table - forget it, you _never_ _ever_ do that directly. Depending on the data you either need to use an official SAP BAPI or a customer created function module that does it for you. You then only call the BAPI/function with NCo.